# PostgreSQL error - NullValueNotAllowed: query string argument of EXECUTE is null

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I try to execute the postgrsql function but run into an error during execution

```
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS weather_crup(jsonb);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION weather_crup(
  input jsonb
)
RETURNS void
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $function$
DECLARE
  _schema_nm character varying;
  _timezone text;
  _id bigint;
BEGIN
SELECT schema_name(l.data_owner_company_id),l.timezone 
 INTO _schema_nm,_timezone
FROM locations l 
 WHERE l.guid = ((input->>'siteGUID')::uuid)
;

WITH input AS (
    SELECT 
      (a->>'siteGUID')::uuid as _site_guid,
      (a->>'diagnosticType') as dg_type,
      (a->>'timeStamp')::timestamp at time zone _timezone at time zone 'UTC' as ts,
      (a->>'value')::double precision as val
    FROM jsonb_array_elements(input) AS e(a)
  ),
dev_ins as (
INSERT INTO devices(
    data_owner_company_id, name, description,ext_supplier_id,device_type_id, unit_number)
    SELECT l.data_owner_company_id,l.name,l.description,
    RTRIM(l.id||'.0.WEATHER'),
    (SELECT id from device_types where name ='FCT/Weather'),'0'
FROM input i JOIN 
locations l ON l.guid = i._site_guid
RETURNING devices.*
)
SELECT id 
INTO _id 
FROM dev_ins
;
EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO' ||_schema_nm||'.telemetries(diagnostic_type_id, device_id, value, ts)
SELECT (SELECT id from diagnostic_types where name =dg_type),'||_id||',input.ts,input.val
FROM input,dev_ins
ON CONFLICT (diagnostic_type_id, ts, device_id) DO NOTHING';
END
;
$function$
;
```

When i execute the function like this in python:

```
cur.execute("SELECT weather_crup( %s )", (json_object,) )
```

I get the error:

> NullValueNotAllowed: query string argument of EXECUTE is null
> CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function weather_crup(jsonb) line 35 at EXECUTE

Comment: Seems either _schema_nm or _id is null.

Comment: Also `input.ts,input.val` is not matching `value, ts`. Further not sure what this `input,dev_ins` is doing as `input` is `jsonb` and you can't join to it like that. Then there is: `WITH input AS ...` pretty sure that is not going to play well with the `input` jsonb parameter in the function signature.

Comment: `EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO'` should be ``EXECUTE 'INSERT INTO ' `, Can you share relevant sample table data in https://dbfiddle.uk/ then we can more easily figure out the probelm.